# Add a filter to an Amazon SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I want to send filtered messages from Amazon SNS topics to Amazon SQS queues. However I want to add a filter policy at the end of SQS. That is, I want to add the filter policy while creating the SQS queue.

I know we can do this at end of an Amazon SNS topic. At the topic end we can add the filter policy but I want to do that while creating the SQS queue.

Can you all suggest any way how we can do this on console?

Comment: Filters can be applied to Amazon SNS subscribers to limit which subscribers receive a message. However, filters cannot be applied to Amazon SQS queues. What would you expect an SQS filter to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add filter to SQS, but since you mentioned Lambda I am assuming that you want to trigger a lambda based on some filtering. This is possible.
Please see this cloudformation template that triggers a lambda only if the content of the message in SQS contains this key-value pair `event_type:telemetry`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Test SQS Lambda Trigger with filtering"

Resources:
  SQSQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties: 
      DelaySeconds: 0
      KmsDataKeyReusePeriodSeconds: 3600 #every 1 hour
      KmsMasterKeyId: 'alias/aws/sqs'
      MaximumMessageSize: 262144 # 256Kb
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 345600 # 4Days
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0
      VisibilityTimeout: 600
  
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Architectures: 
        - arm64
      Runtime: python3.9
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            print(event)
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 30
      Description: Invoke Lambda on SQS events
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
  
  LambdaFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
        - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess'

  LambdaPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: LambdaPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sqs:*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref LambdaFunctionRole

  LambdaSourceMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties: 
      BatchSize: 1
      Enabled: True
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
      FilterCriteria:
        Filters: 
          - Pattern: "{\"body\": {\"event_type\": [\"telemetry\"]}}"
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
      MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 1
```